# How do I make my img:hover code work with two different codes?

Tags: html

how do i make an image have an animation (on hover) without having to add img:hover, because it breaks the code for me once i add another image with a hover element. I want the cat image to shake on hover, but the rose image Not to shake.

```html
<style>
#yes {
}

img:hover {
/* Start the shake animation and make the animation last for 0.5 seconds */
animation: shake 0.5s;
/* When the animation is finished, start again */
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes shake {
0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
60% { transform
: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}


.rose {
position:absolute; 
height: 60px; 
position: absolute; 
right: 10%;
bottom: 65%; 
z-index: 10; 

}
</style>


<a href="link"><img class=rose src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/yE37tIxmy_UX0kF8GPWUE8IENQgG5N5LWThSxPW2Hf98oV2okclLeqBa9eoB8dafwEc2xryoRZZEdsyboPpFmz-NMi2nQOPhy2QU3hu5fJ5EBXCQOA_QpDnz"></a>


<div id="yes"><img src="https://media.tenor.com/images/eff22afc2220e9df92a7aa2f53948f9f/tenor.gif">
```

Answer (score 1):

img will target all images on page as you already experienced. You can use the different CSS selectors such as the class .rose for targeting the rose only. Since the cat is wrapped in a div with the ID of #yes, you can use that for targeting the cat only.

Here updated code:

```html
<style>

#yes:hover {
/* Start the shake animation and make the animation last for 0.5 seconds */
animation: shake 0.5s;
/* When the animation is finished, start again */
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes shake {
0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
60% { transform
: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}


.rose {
position:absolute; 
height: 60px; 
position: absolute; 
right: 10%;
bottom: 65%; 
z-index: 10; 

}
</style>


<a href="link"><img class=rose src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/yE37tIxmy_UX0kF8GPWUE8IENQgG5N5LWThSxPW2Hf98oV2okclLeqBa9eoB8dafwEc2xryoRZZEdsyboPpFmz-NMi2nQOPhy2QU3hu5fJ5EBXCQOA_QpDnz"></a>


<div id="yes"><img src="https://media.tenor.com/images/eff22afc2220e9df92a7aa2f53948f9f/tenor.gif"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img:hover
```

does effect all images on hover. So you have to seperate animations with different selectors. For example:

```
.rose:hover
.cat:hover
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your animation into a class that you only use for it. Like:

```
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.imgAnimation:hover {
  animation: example 4s ease-in-out infinit;
}

@keyframes shake {
0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
60% { transform
: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
```

And then you can put a class that has you hover animation just into the images you want

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img1.png">
  <img class="imgAnimation" src="img2.jpg">
  <img class="imgAnimation" src="img3.jpg">
</div>
```